# Can you explain this code to me? (.replace)

Tags: javascript, arrays, replace

I had a Kata which wanted me to convert to leetSpeak. I was able to google a similar enough solution to make it work. I'm quite a beginner and was hoping somebody could explain to me exactly how this code works so that I can impliment it in future. I understand the .replace and the search value but not really the new value.
Here is the code:

```
function toLeetSpeak(str) {
    var leet = str.replace(/[A-Z]/g, function(str, p1, p2, offset, leet) {
        var translate_table = { 
            A : '@',
            B : '8',
            C : '(',
            D : 'D',
            E : '3',
            F : 'F',
            G : '6',
            H : '#',
            I : '!',
            J : 'J',
            K : 'K',
            L : '1',
            M : 'M',
            N : 'N',
            O : '0',
            P : 'P',
            Q : 'Q',
            R : 'R',
            S : '$',
            T : '7',
            U : 'U',
            V : 'V',
            W : 'W',
            X : 'X',
            Y : 'Y',
            Z : '2' 
        };
        return translate_table[str];
    });
    return leet;
}
```

Edit for clarity:
I get what the code is doing, it's more than I don't get how. What are the various arguments going into the function and how does that mean that I am able to insert the key?

Comment: [MDN replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Comment: Replace a capital alphabet by it's value in that object for all(`g`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better written like this.

You essentially have a replacer dictionary and for each match you replace the matched substring with an associated character.

```js
const LEET_SPEAK_DICT = { 
  A : '@',    B : '8',    C : '(',    D : 'D',
  E : '3',    F : 'F',    G : '6',    H : '#',
  I : '!',    J : 'J',    K : 'K',    L : '1',
  M : 'M',    N : 'N',    O : '0',    P : 'P',
  Q : 'Q',    R : 'R',    S : '$',    T : '7',
  U : 'U',    V : 'V',    W : 'W',    X : 'X',
  Y : 'Y',    Z : '2'
};

function toLeetSpeak(str) {
  return translate(str, LEET_SPEAK_DICT);
}

function translate(phrase, dictionary) {
  return phrase.replace(/[A-Z]/g, function(str, p1, p2, offset, original) {
    return dictionary[str];
  });
}

console.log(toLeetSpeak('Hello World'.toUpperCase()));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

---

You could also write it as a key reducer.

```js
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search, replacement) {
  return this.replace(new RegExp(search, 'g'), replacement);
};

const LEET_SPEAK_DICT = {
  A : '@',    B : '8',    C : '(',    D : 'D',
  E : '3',    F : 'F',    G : '6',    H : '#',
  I : '!',    J : 'J',    K : 'K',    L : '1',
  M : 'M',    N : 'N',    O : '0',    P : 'P',
  Q : 'Q',    R : 'R',    S : '$',    T : '7',
  U : 'U',    V : 'V',    W : 'W',    X : 'X',
  Y : 'Y',    Z : '2'
};

function toLeetSpeak(str) {
  return translate(str, LEET_SPEAK_DICT);
}

function translate(str, dict) {
  return Object.keys(dict).reduce((s, k) => s.replaceAll(k, dict[k]), str);
}

console.log(toLeetSpeak('Hello World'.toUpperCase()));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: It took me a while to get to the point to understand how helpful your answer is.. thanks!